# How to use data-target into differents components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to add a modal from bootstrap into my code and I'm using Angular2+ (6 exactly) for the front-end part. The problem is that the button I use to call the modal is into another component than the modal itself, so it doesn't work as expected.

In one component, the Siderbar one, i have those lines of code:

```
<li *ngIf="!userService.mainUser" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"  style="cursor: pointer">
    <a>
        <i class="mdi mdi-login"></i>
        <span class="hide-menu">Se connecter</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

As you can see, I have a `data-toggle="modal"` and a `data-target="#login"` in my `<li>` to open my modal when I click.

The problem is that my modal's code is into another component, the Login one:

```
<div id="login" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-title">
        <h1 style="margin-left: 15px">Se connecter</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
          <input name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label">Mot de passe</label>
          <input name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input style="display: inline" type="checkbox">
          <label style="margin-left: 10px"> Rester connecté ?</label>
        </div>

        <button (click)="logIn()" [ngStyle]="{'background': appFade, 'color': getTextColor()}">Se connecter</button>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

So when I click on the "Se connecter" button, it doesn't open my modal, and I don't know how to make it works.

I hope my question is clear and that you will be able to help me.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the component selector to the html where your button is

```
    <li *ngIf="!userService.mainUser" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"  style="cursor: pointer">
    <a>
        <i class="mdi mdi-login"></i>
        <span class="hide-menu">Se connecter</span>
    </a>
</li>
<app-login-modal></app-login-modal>//this should coincide with the name modals selector name in your typescript file
```